# exim "emulating" Outlook configuration via Cygwin?

Tags: scripting, cygwin, exim

I would like to send an e-mail using Cygwin.

I have installed *exim* and want to use the same config as what I have in Outlook at the moment to send the mail (my company SMTP, my own e-mail, etc) without screwing up Outlook in the process.

Is that possible ?

Note that the SH script that will send the mail MUST be installed on numerous machines (not on a single server). It's a website deployment script using an RSYNC command that must send a mail to the development team.

Answer (score 1):

Your method and Outlook are two different clients to the mail servers (your office and other personal servers) that you interact with. There should be no impact to Outlook.

In short, one mail-sending client cannot impact anther mail-sending/receiving client.